# Kernel of differentiation operator over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Define $W$ analogously, but consisting only of the polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n-1$. Find the kernel of the differentiation operator $T: V \to W$ sending $p \mapsto p'(x)$.

The first thing I am not fully certain about is how to interpret the degree $n$. I believe I don't "reduce this mod $p$," but rather take it as a fixed positive integer, possibly greater than $p$, and focus only on the coefficients as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

The first thing I would do for any such polynomial is say that $p(x) \in V$ has the form $p(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and some -- potentially all -- of the coefficients could be zero, so the polynomial could have degree strictly less than $n$. Taking its derivative and setting it equal to $0$, I get
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{d}{dx} a_i x^i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i a_i x^{i-1} = 0 = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n 0 x^i. 
$$
The first observation is that if $\deg(p) = 1$, then $T(p) = 0$, so $p$ is certainly in the kernel. Over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, I would need
$$
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, \; ia_i \equiv 0 \pmod p.
$$
As $p$ is prime, this is true if and only if either $i \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $a_i \equiv p \pmod p$. I'm not sure if I can say anything about the indices $i$ if I'm treating the $n$ as fixed. Certainly if $a_i$ is a multiple of $p$ for every $p$, or if $i a_i$ is a multiple of $p$ for each $i$, then that polynomial is in the kernel. Otherwise, it will have at least one non-zero coefficient. I don't know how to formalize this or how to treat the issue of the indices (or the degree $n$).

Comment: If you wish to deal with a vector space, you need to have $p$ prime, otherwise you work with modules

Comment: When you say polynomials of degree $1$ are mapped to zero, you mean polynomials of degree *zero*, not $1$. For instance, $p(x)=x$ has degree $1$ and is mapped to $1\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correctly identified that the monomial $x^i$ will vanish if $p$ divides $i$ regardless of the coefficient and that linear combinations of these monomials will be in the kernel.

To see that this is the entire kernel we need to ensure that $ia_i \neq 0$ when $i \nmid k $. To see this note that $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ does not have zero divisors because $p$ is prime. This means if $ia_i = 0$ we must have $a_i=0$ since $i \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z} /p \mathbb{Z}$. So this means that polynomials of the form $f(x^p)$ characterize the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two cases (but I believe you just work in the first)

1. $p$ is prime, you work with vector spaces and as you could tell with your own computations, $\ker \partial = Span(X^{pk})_{k\leqslant n/p}$. Indeed, if $p$ is prime $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, hence $ia_i = 0 \mod p \iff a_i = 0 \mod p \text{ or } i=0 \mod p$.
2. $p=m$ is not, then you work with $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ modules (not a vector space but almost)
   In this case, your ring is not even an integral domain. Your kernel is given by
   $$\ker \partial = \bigoplus_{k\leq n} \ker (a \mapsto ka) X^k$$

If $k\wedge m = 1$, you have $\ker (a \mapsto ka) = \{0\}$

If $k \wedge m = d >1$, $\ker (a \mapsto ka) = \frac{m}{d}\cdot \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$
So you get
$$\ker \partial = \bigoplus_{k\leq n} \left(\frac{m}{k\wedge m}\cdot \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\right) X^k \simeq \bigoplus_{k\leq n} \mathbb{Z}/(k\wedge m)\mathbb{Z}$$
This gives you the right result for $p=m$ prime since $k\wedge p = 1 \text{ or } p$ depending on the divisibility of $k$ by $p$.